# Conditional Styles in react

Tags: reactjs

I am making a todo list and in the following `Tasks` component I have an `li` component with mapped data.
I want to conditionally add a strikethrough on the task for which I used a `useState` hook with initial property as `null`.

I then added `onClick` functions to change state to `true` and `false` respectively but my style is not being applied :(

Below is the code for the same

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./Tasks.css";
import DoneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Done';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

function Tasks(props) {

  const [done, setDone] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="tasks">
        {props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id} onClick={() => setDone(false)} style={{textDecorationLine: done && 'line-through'}}>{item.text} 
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => setDone(true)} style={{color: "green"}}><DoneIcon/></button>
              <button style={{color: "red"}}><CloseIcon/></button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues:

1. If you want to save the state for each task, you can't use a single boolean. You need and array or object that holds one value per task.
2. When you click your Done button, both `onClick` callbacks are triggered (the one for `<button>` and the one for `<li>`), setting the value of `done` to `true` and immediately to `false` again.

To solve [1], you can make your `done` variable an object, where each key is an item id and matching value is a boolean that determines if the task is done.

To solve [2], remove `onClick` from the `<li>`. You can still achieve a toggle effect if you set the task state based on previous state, in the button's `onClick`.

The following code should be what you need:

```
  // done is an object that maps task ids to booleans
  const [done, setDone] = useState({});

  return (
    <div className="tasks">
      {props.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} style={{textDecorationLine: done[item.id] && 'line-through'}}>{item.text} 
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setDone(prevState => ({...prevState, [item.id]: !prevState[item.id]}))} style={{color: "green"}}><DoneIcon/></button>
            <button style={{color: "red"}}><CloseIcon/></button>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: you better write `done[item.id] ? 'line-through' : undefined` because `x && y` is either going to return `y` or `false`

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the `item.id` to determine which item was clicked, not a boolean.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./Tasks.css";
import DoneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Done';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

function Tasks(props) {

  const [taskWasDone, setTaskWasDone] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="tasks">
        {props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id} onClick={() => setTaskWasDone(null)} style={{textDecorationLine: taskWasDone === item.id && 'line-through'}}>{item.text} 
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setTaskWasDone(item.id)} style={{color: "green"}}><DoneIcon/></button>
            <button style={{color: "red"}}><CloseIcon/></button>
          </div>
      </li>
        ))}
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tasks;
```